# Want to print results on a new line with every click. Working on Rock, Scissors, Paper project

Tags: javascript

I am working on the Rock Paper Scissors project from The Odin Project.

Here is the interface I've come up with so far: https://catito1990.github.io/RockPaperScissors/

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Everytime a button is clicked, the results should show up in a new line.

What happens instead:

- They show up next to each other, on the same line.

What I've tried:

- Putting a \n at the end and/or beginning of each string answer (didn't work); manipulating DOM to create new 'p' element, or 'br' element, storing in a 'const newLine' variable and adding as a " + newLine" after each string (just shows up as [HTMLElementp or HTMLElementbr] in the browser); adding each as a new list item (didn't work).

What on god's green earth do I need to do to just have them appear on separate lines?

The code is here: https://github.com/Catito1990/RockPaperScissors/blob/main/javascript.js . There's a lot of extra elements that I haven't gotten around to working with yet because I've just been stuck on this one simple thing for 2 days.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Post code as a [mcve] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a `p` element with id "scorecard". Just make it a div and apply the style

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
```

Then, everytime a round finishes, append a `p` element with the phrases about that match. Everytime you append a new `p` element, they will automatically go on a next line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried that and it still wasn't working, turns out i just needed to change the .addTextContent to .innerHTML. Now it's good, thank you!